# Como agregar elementos a un array con numpy

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy

Bueno sé que es algo de novatos, o eso creo pero espero que me puedan ayudar.

Intento agregar elementos a una array, este tipo de elementos son coordenadas (geozonas de hecho, son varias coordenadas que hacen un poligono) y cada uno se separa por un objeto.

Intentare explicarlo por partes:

```
def poligono(self):
        # arrays para primera parte
        geozone = np.array([])
        geoz = np.array([])

        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        db = client.siete.geozonas
        res = db.find({}, {"_id": 0, "id": 0, "__v": 0})

        for geo in res:
            print(geo['points'][0])
```

La primera parte del código, hacemos la consulta a todas la *geocercas*, y recorremos para que nos muestre los datos.

```
[{'x': -106.36735534667969, 'y': 31.613407135009766}, {'x': -106.36652374267578, 'y': 31.613983154296875}, {'x': -106.36567687988281, 'y': 31.61317253112793}, {'x': -106.3666000366211, 'y': 31.612560272216797}, {'x': -106.36735534667969, 'y': 31.613407135009766}]
[{'x': -100.44711303710938, 'y': 20.765583038330078}, {'x': -100.4467544555664, 'y': 20.76490020751953}, {'x': -100.44577026367188, 'y': 20.764829635620117}, {'x': -100.4465560913086, 'y': 20.765995025634766}, {'x': -100.44711303710938, 'y': 20.765583038330078}]
[{'x': -100.88704681396484, 'y': 20.16451644897461}, {'x': -100.88524627685547, 'y': 20.16451644897461}, {'x': -100.88524627685547, 'y': 20.163314819335938}, {'x': -100.88704681396484, 'y': 20.163314819335938}, {'x': -100.88704681396484, 'y': 20.16451644897461}]
[{'x': -106.32225036621094, 'y': 31.732959747314453}, {'x': -106.32258605957031, 'y': 31.731849670410156}, {'x': -106.32339477539062, 'y': 31.732032775878906}, {'x': -106.32306671142578, 'y': 31.733165740966797}, {'x': -106.32225036621094, 'y': 31.732959747314453}]
```

Esto es lo que me regresa (obvio son muy pocas a comparacion de toda la cantidad de datos que tengo), lo que quiero es que esa información se guarde en un array para poder seguir trabajandolo ya que necesito que quede un arreglo con solo las coordenadas, sin los 'x' y 'y'

Utilizo numpy y cuando esta en el ciclo `for` utilizo el siguiente código :

```
def poligono(self):
        # arrays para primera parte
        geozone = np.array([])

        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        db = client.siete.geozonas
        res = db.find({}, {"_id": 0, "id": 0, "__v": 0})

        for geo in res:
            geozone = np.append(geozone, geo['points'][0])
        
        print(geozone)
```

pero al mostrar el valor

```
[{'x': -106.36735534667969, 'y': 31.613407135009766}
 {'x': -106.36652374267578, 'y': 31.613983154296875}
 {'x': -106.36567687988281, 'y': 31.61317253112793} ...
 {'x': -108.97021484375, 'y': 25.792675018310547}
 {'x': -108.97201538085938, 'y': 25.792675018310547}
 {'x': -108.97201538085938, 'y': 25.793874740600586}]
```

Esto es lo que me trae ....

Esta es la estructura que tengo dentro de mongodb

```
"GeoName" : "SOLDADURAS",
    "points" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "x" : -106.36735534668,
                "y" : 31.6134071350098
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.366523742676,
                "y" : 31.6139831542969
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.365676879883,
                "y" : 31.6131725311279
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.366600036621,
                "y" : 31.6125602722168
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.36735534668,
                "y" : 31.6134071350098
            }
        ]
    ]
```

No sé si estoy haciendo algo mal, pero si necesito algo de ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Supongamos que lo que quieres obtener es un array bidimensional en el que cada fila contiene un par (x,y), es decir, algo como esto:

```
[[-106.36735535,   31.61340714],
 [-106.36652374,   31.61398315],
 [-106.36567688,   31.61317253],
 [-106.36660004,   31.61256027],
 [-106.36735535,   31.61340714]]
```

En ese caso debes construir previamente una lista python normal, que contenga esa secuencia de parejas, y luego convertir la lista en array numpy. Algo como lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```py
all_points = []

for geo in res:
    all_points.extend([(p["x"], p["y"]) for p in geo['points'][0]])
```

Esto producirá en `all_points` la lista:

```
[(-106.36735534668, 31.6134071350098),
 (-106.366523742676, 31.6139831542969),
 (-106.365676879883, 31.6131725311279),
 (-106.366600036621, 31.6125602722168),
 (-106.36735534668, 31.6134071350098)]
```

y ya sólo queda hacer:

```
geopoints = np.array(all_points)
```

Si lo que quieres es obtener un array bidimensional en el que la primera fila tenga todas las coordenadas X y la segunda fila todas las coordenadas Y, basta hacer la transpuesta del array anterior, es decir, `geopoints.T` y obtendrías:

```
[[-106.36735535, -106.36652374, -106.36567688, -106.36660004, -106.36735535],
 [  31.61340714,   31.61398315,   31.61317253,   31.61256027,  31.61340714]]
```

Comment: me genero ya sin las x y y, me mando un arreglo enorme de las coordenadas, habria alguna forma de que por cada geocerza me generara un arreglo individual ?

Se que no me explique bien en la pregunta, realmente me ayudo mucho!